# Is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException.Number the same in all version's of SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, version, sqlexception

I want to categorize the `SQL Exception` only for *`Login failed for user 'username'`* message on catch block. So I tried this way.

```
   if(exception.Number == 18456)
       return false;
   else
       throw exception;
```

I want to `throw all other exception` other than login failed.

Is the Number I am using here the same for this error text in all version's of Sql Server?

Comment: @marc_s answer my question with the source you found which is enough to take decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Server error codes don't change - once defined they stay the same, new error codes might be added with each version, but existing ones stay the same.

[See this link for a list of all SQL Server error codes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) as of version 2008 R2.

Those messages (or message templates, with placeholders) are surfaced in the [`sys.messages`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187382%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) system catalog view.